# How to make custom navigation with WordPress (wp-bootstrap-nawalker)

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating theme with WordPress and I'm using default bootstrap navbar for navigation.

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li class="active"><a class="scroll" href="#home">HOME</a></li>
   <li><a class="scroll" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li><a class="scroll" href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
   <li><a class="scroll" href="#team">TEAM</a></li>
   <li><a class="scroll" href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
   <li><a class="scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li> 
 </ul>
```

I was using wp-bootstrap-nawalker https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker for creating my navigation dynamic.

```
  wp_nav_menu( array(
          'menu'            => 'primary',
          'theme_location'  => 'primary',
          'depth'           =>  2,
          'container'       => 'div',
          'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
          'container_id'    => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
          'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
          'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
          'walker'          => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
        ));
```

Which is working fine. But I can't see `scroll` class inside my anchor tags. I can't see any options in wp-bootstrap-navwalker to customize my anchor tags.

The Problem: I'm having `scroll` class in my anchor tags. `<a class="scroll"></a>`. Is there any way to put scroll class inside my anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add class inside anchor tags, you need to edit bootstrap_navwalker.php ( lines 80 -94 )

```
        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->title )   ? $item->title  : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )  ? $item->target : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )     ? $item->xfn    : '';
        $atts['class']  = 'scroll'; // class for anchor tag

        // If item has_children add atts to a.
        if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) {
            $atts['href']           = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
            $atts['data-toggle']    = '';
            $atts['class']          = 'scroll dropdown-toggle'; // class for dropdown anchor tag
            $atts['aria-haspopup']  = 'true';
        } else {
            $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
        }
```

wp-bootstrap-navwalker recently updated to 2.0.5, so you may want to update and the lines you need to modify may have changed.